# How to Smoothly Distort a Pattern in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, distort

In trying to improve my Illustrator skills, I'm imitating some posters. Currently, I'm onto the one below.

What I'm having trouble with is the distorted background. I tried to convert a dot pattern to outlines and then move them somehow, but I don't know how to move them with a falloff, such that a smooth transition happens.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vector illustration software (such as Adobe Illustrator) you'd likely do this via [envelop distort](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KPHYfDVq_0).

This particular example, however, appears to have been done via analog means. It looks like someone took an image, placed it on a scanner, then moved it while it was being scanned.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Da01's great suggestion regarding envelope distort....

Illustrator does also have **Warp Tools**:

[image]

Which can allow you to manually push/pull things around:

[image]

I do also agree with DA01 that it looks more like a scanner and movement overall though.